# how to start linux shell dynamically

Tags: bash, shell, kernel, init

Below is the inittab file entry for starting shell.

```
::respawn:/bin/bash < /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/ttyS0 2> /dev/ttyS0
```

My question is, I am reading a config file which says on which tty port `/bin/bash` needs to respawned. File content may be `ttyS0`, `ttyS1` or `ttyS2`.

How can I respawn `/bin/bash` based on file content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your config file is `/etc/dynshell.cfg` and contains the device name (like `ttyS0`) on one line, and nothing else, you can write this…

```
#!/bin/sh
port=/dev/$(</etc/dynshell.cfg)
exec /bin/bash <$port >$port 2>$port
```

… into `/usr/local/sbin/dynshell`, then use this line:

```
::respawn:/usr/local/sbin/dynshell
```

Although this might be better/safer:

```
#!/bin/sh
port=/dev/$(</etc/dynshell.cfg)
exec /bin/bash 0<>$port >&0 2>&0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.if we run exec it only spawns /bin/bash once right? where as respawn will again spawn /bin/bash if somebody kill/exited the shell.